# Possible to use a tapestry application for webservice and web front end development

Tags: tapestry

I want to use tapestry application for both web-services and front end development. Is it possible to acieve in a single tapestry application.

Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

This has been just answered in the mailing list:
http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Possible-to-use-a-tapestry-application-for-webservice-and-web-front-end-development-td5726651.html

http://killertilapia.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/easy-restful-services-with-tapestry-and.html

check also [Tapestry + REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765178/tapestry-rest)